# How do I prove that the vectors $\vec v_1$, and $\vec v_2$ form a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

I know that for vectors to form a basis, they must span the subspace. Other than that, I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known theorem that eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent .Also every $n$ linearly independent vector in $n$ dimensional vector space is a basis for vector space.